# hosting multiple Flask apps for unique domains

Tags: python, apache, flask, dns, virtualhost

I have two unique domains (eg. `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`). I am trying to host two unique webpages (via two separate flask apps) on one linode server (eg. `12.34.567.890`) using Flask.

Currently, `domain1.com` works, but `domain2.com` gives me the Apache2 default page.

Here's what I have so far:
etc\apache2\ports.conf:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

etc\apache2\sites-available\000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

etc\apache2\sites-available\FlaskApp.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName domain1.com
            ServerAdmin admin@email.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/AppOne/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/AppOne/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/AppOne/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/AppOne/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
            ServerName domain2.com
            ServerAdmin admin@email.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/AppTwo/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/AppTwo/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/AppTwo/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/AppTwo/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`__init__.py` for each app is the same (but in different directories):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, url_for, redirect, session
from content_management import Content
#...etc...
import gc

TOPIC_DICT = Content()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The \var\www\ directory looks like this:

```
\var\www
|
└─── AppOne
|    |    flaskapp.wsgi
|    |
|    └─── FlaskApp
|         |  __init__.py
|         |
|         └─── static
|         └─── templates
|         |        home.html
|         |
|         └─── venv
|
└─── AppTwo                  #same as AppOne
     |    flaskapp.wsgi
     |
     └─── FlaskApp
          |  __init__.py
          |
          └─── static
          └─── templates
          |        home.html
          |
          └─── venv
```

Sorry if I got a bit verbose, but any guidance would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to listen on port 8080. WSGI file for AppTwo wasn't point to the right directory.

ports.conf:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

FlaskApp.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain1.com
        ServerAdmin admin@email.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/AppOne/flaskapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/AppOne/FlaskApp/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/AppOne/FlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www/AppOne/FlaskApp/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAdmin admin@email.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/AppTwo/flaskapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/AppTwo/FlaskApp/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/AppTwo/FlaskApp/static
        <Directory /var/www/AppTwo/FlaskApp/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

AppOne/flaskapp.wsgi:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/AppOne/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'PasswordGoesHere'
```

AppTwo/flaskapp.wsgi:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/AppTwo/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'PasswordGoesHere'
```