# Certbot certificates not working on Apache for multiple Flask sites sharing an IP address

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask, ssl-certificate

After two days of trying, I am completely at a loss with adding a certificate to my second domain. Here is my situation:

**What works:** 
I have a dynamic site (domain1 / site1) hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu. It is served using Apache and uses the Flask microframework. Everything works correctly, and I was able to install a Let's Encrypt certificate successfully using certbot.

I have added a second dynamic site (domain2 / site2) to the same droplet, sharing the single IP across the two domains/sites. I was able to get this working by following this answer: [hosting multiple Flask apps for unique domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105259/hosting-multiple-flask-apps-for-unique-domains). Now I can: 
(1) visit site1 via domain1 over HTTPS like I always could
(2) visit site2 via domain2 over HTTP.

**What doesn't:** 
The problem comes in when I try to add a new Let's Encrypt certificate to site2/domain2. The [tutorial at Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-let-s-encrypt-certificates-for-multiple-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04) and the [certbot documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-commands) suggest all I need to do is run certbot again with the new domain. A new certificate is created, but best case scenario, site1 becomes a "potential security risk" and site2 is still insecure.

Below are the contents of /etc/apache2/sites-available/ files BEFORE I attempt to install the second certificate.

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp>
                Options +ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.py
        </Directory>
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/FlaskApp
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

FlaskApp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.audiologysource.com
                ServerAlias audiologysource.com
                #ServerName 157.245.135.241
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.audiologysource.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =audiologysource.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.travismmoore.com
                ServerAlias travismmoore.com
                ServerAdmin youemail@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

FlaskApp-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName www.audiologysource.com
                ServerAlias audiologysource.com
                #ServerName 157.245.135.241
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/audiologysource.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/audiologysource.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

My /var/www directory is organized like this:

```
\var\www
|
└─── FlaskApp
|    |    flaskapp.wsgi
|    |
|    └─── FlaskApp
|         |  __init__.py
|         |
|         └─── static
|         └─── templates
|         |        home.html
|         |
|         └─── venv
|
└─── PersonalSiteApp                  #same as FlaskApp
     |    flaskapp.wsgi
     |
     └─── FlaskApp
          |  __init__.py
          |
          └─── static
          └─── templates
          |        home.html
          |
          └─── venv
```

Here are the same files AFTER I run certbot and reload Apache:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d travismmoore.com -d www.travismmoore.com
```

000-default.conf: unchanged

FlaskApp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.audiologysource.com
                ServerAlias audiologysource.com
                #ServerName 157.245.135.241
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.audiologysource.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =audiologysource.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanen$
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.travismmoore.com
                ServerAlias travismmoore.com
                ServerAdmin youemail@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/flaskapp.w$
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =audiologysource.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.audiologysource.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =travismmoore.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanen$
</VirtualHost>
```

FlaskApp-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName www.audiologysource.com
                ServerAlias audiologysource.com
                #ServerName 157.245.135.241
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias travismmoore.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/travismmoore.com/fullchain.p$
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/travismmoore.com/privkey.$
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName www.travismmoore.com
                ServerAlias travismmoore.com
                ServerAdmin youemail@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/flaskapp.w$
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName www.travismmoore.com
ServerAlias travismmoore.com
                ServerAdmin youemail@email.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/flaskapp.w$
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static
                <Directory /var/www/PersonalSiteApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/travismmoore.com/fullchain.p$
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/travismmoore.com/privkey.$
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd update this with what ended up working for those who run into the same issue. I ended up having to remove all the certificates, then add them one at a time manually, using:

```
sudo certbot --manual certonly -d domain_1.com -d www.domain_1.com
sudo certbot --manual certonly -d domain_2.com -d www.domain_2.com
```